# Dynamic Update SQL query in asp.net not working with variables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web

I have the following code for updating data on a simple form:

```
protected void BUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = Convert.ToInt32(Sid.Text);
    comm = "UPDATE tblStaff SET Name = @sname, Gender = @sex, Phone = @phone, Address = @address, Position = @position, Salary = @salary WHERE (ID = @id)";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(comm, cn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", i );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", Sname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", DropDownList1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", Sposition.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", Ssalary.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Saddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Sphone.Text);

    r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (r > 0)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Success')</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Failed')</script>");
    }
}
```

When I replace the "i" in:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", i );
```

the code runs perfectly, but when I use variable, it throws an error.

I have tried using `Sid.Text` and `Convert.toInt32(Sid.text)` in place of "i" but both are not working.

Please help.

Comment: You should read this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the error you are getting....huge faux pas.  But here's a guess at a solution:

Try specifying the type of the id column.  Something like this (make sure you are using the correct [SqlDbType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = i;
```